# $ (H, \alpha) $ is lie subgroup of $G$, $\exp(tY) \in \alpha(H)$, How to prove $Y \in \alpha_\ast (h)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> $ (H, \alpha) $ is lie subgroup of $G$, $\exp(tY) \in \alpha(H)$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, How to prove $ Y \in \alpha_\ast (h)$? where $h$ is the lie algebra of $H$.

When I encounter this exc, the first thought in my mind is take the $t_0$ small enough, and the exponential map is homeomorphism in the neighborhood $V$ of the identity, therefore
$$\exp(t_0Y) = \alpha(X) = \alpha(\exp(Y^{\prime})) = \exp(\alpha_\ast(Y^{\prime}))$$

hence, $t_0Y = \alpha_\ast(Y^{\prime}) \in \alpha_\ast(h)$.

But the $\exp(tY)$ may not be the uniparametric subgroups of $ \alpha(H) $,
and $ \alpha(H) $ may not be lie group. I have no idea to work out this question. And I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The map $t\rightarrow \exp(tY)$ is a differentiable map defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and takes its values in $\alpha(H)$. This implies that its differential at $t$ is a map $T_t\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \alpha(H)_{\exp(tY)}$ in particular if $t=0$ we have: ${d\over{dt}}_{t=0}\exp(tY)=Y$ is an element of $T_{Id}\alpha(H)=\alpha_*(h)$.

Comment: But  $\alpha(H)$ may not be a submanifold of $G$, how to get the tangent spaces?